# Termcaps lines and columns are not changing when I resize the window

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm trying to get the terminal window size, even when I resize the window, I'm using termcaps for this, the problem is when I resize the window, the values of lines and columns stays the same instead of updating, I also tried using ncurses's LINES and COLS globals, but the same thing happens.
Here is a minimal reproductible example:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <term.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char * term_type = getenv("TERM");
    int ret;
    int li_cap;
    int co_cap;

    if (!term_type)
    {
        write(2, "TERM env must be set\n", 21);
        return (-1);
    }
    if ((ret = tgetent(NULL, term_type)) == -1)
    {
        write(2, "Could not access to the termcap database\n", 41);
        return (-1);
    }
    if (!ret)
    {
        write(2, "This terminal is not supported by termcaps\n", 43);
        return (-1);
    }
    while (1)
    {
        sleep(1);
        li_cap = tgetnum("li");
        co_cap = tgetnum("co");
        printf("%d %d\n", li_cap, co_cap);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

So when I resize the window inside the loop, the values stay the same, I want to get the lines and colums in real time, how could I do this with termcaps?

Comment: maybe this issue can be solved by `use_tioctl(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The termcap data and the environment variables `COLUMNS` and `LINES` are unreliable and aren't updated upon terminal resizing, especially during program execution. There is another solution for POSIX systems where you can:

- retrieve the size of the terminal window with `ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws)`
- register a signal handler to get notified of terminal size changes.

Here is a demonstration program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static volatile unsigned char term_size_updated;

static void term_resize() {
    term_size_updated = 1;
}

static void term_get_size(int *cols, int *rows) {
    struct winsize ws;

    /* get screen dimensions from (pseudo) tty ioctl */
    if (ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws) == 0) {
        *cols = ws.ws_col;
        *rows = ws.ws_row;
    } else {
        *cols = *rows = -1;
    }
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction sig;
    int cols, rows;

    /* set up terminal resize callback */
    sig.sa_handler = term_resize;
    sigemptyset(&sig.sa_mask);
    sig.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGWINCH, &sig, NULL);

    term_size_updated = 1;
    for (;;) {
        if (term_size_updated) {
            term_size_updated = 0;
            term_get_size(&cols, &rows);
            fprintf(stderr, "term_resize: cols=%d, rows=%d\n", cols, rows);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're going to run into race conditions with this code. `term_updated` should be a `volatile sig_atomic_t`. Another alternative is to use the "self-pipe trick".

Comment: @michaelmeyer: indeed this program is a quick and dirty example. No provision is made to protect variables accessed by interrupt driven code.

Comment: @michaelmeyer what is a sig_atomic_t?

Comment: I am not sure if ioctl()s are signal-safe.

Comment: @Fayeure See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t

Comment: @michaelmeyer: I updated the code to avoid making system calls from a signal handler and only update a volatile byte variable when signalled.

Comment: @chqrlie yes, thank you, sorry for the wait, I forgot to set the answer to accepted

Comment: @chqrlie You are calling the wrong function in the loop. It should be term_get_size(&cols, &rows) not term_resize(&cols, &rows)

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs: good catch! answer updated.